# Lightswitch and Entity Framework

Tags: entity-framework, visual-studio-lightswitch, lightswitch-2012

I am trying to build a simple db application. I learned EF code first approach and liked it. However I don't want to deal with interface design. Lightswitch seems to be right tool to create my CRUD screens easily. What I understand is I can easily develop my application logic, db structure and test it using lightswitch. However I am not sure about how to use lightswitch with EF code first approach. Can you suggest a way to solve my problem?

Comment: By EF code first, I assume you're referring to creating the database from the code, right? My experience with Lightswitch makes me think that's not possible in Lightswitch. You can use the entity designer to create the database, or if you have an existing database, Lightswitch can connect to it.

Comment: I've created a separate project where I keep all EF stuff. Then I connect to the created database using lightswitch.